# Php how to put result from function

Tags: php

```
<?php
function szczesliwy ($od, $do, $ile) {
    $zasieg = range($od, $do);
    $losowe = array_rand($zasieg, $ile);
    $wynik = array();
    foreach ($losowe as $index) {
        $wynik []= $zasieg[$index];
    }   
    return $wynik;
}

szczesliwy(1, 31, 20);
print($wynik);
?>
```

It says 
**Notice:**

> Undefined variable: wynik in C:\xampp\htdocs\21\index.php on line 14

and nothing else happens, and my question is how to put result on screen?

Comment: instead of `szczesliwy(1, 31, 20);
print($wynik);`  write   `$wynik = szczesliwy(1, 31, 20);
print($wynik);`  , you misunderstood variable scope

Answer (score 1):

You need to get what function returns

```
$wynik = szczesliwy(1, 31, 20);
print($wynik);
```

Answer (score 0):

Check the following line:

```
szczesliwy(1, 31, 20);
print($wynik);
```

where $wynik is defined??

Try this:

```
$wynik = szczesliwy(1, 31, 20);
// hold the return value of function
print($wynik);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    <?php
function szczesliwy ($od, $do, $ile) {
$zasieg = range($od, $do);
$losowe = array_rand($zasieg, $ile);
$wynik = array();
foreach ($losowe as $index) {
    $wynik []= $zasieg[$index];
}   
return $wynik;


}
$wynik = szczesliwy(1, 31, 20);
print_r($wynik);
?>
```

Comment: Thanks! That helped a lot.

Comment: While this code snippet may solve the question, [including an explanation](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114762/explaining-entirely-code-based-answers) really helps to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion. Please also try not to crowd your code with explanatory comments, this reduces the readability of both the code and the explanations!

Comment: Don't just code educate as well,you must explain your code for future readers as @Rizier123 have stated above.

Comment: print

Outputs only a single string
Returns 1, so it can be used in an expression

e.g. print "Hello"

or, if ($expr && print "foo")
print_r()

Outputs a human-readable representation of any one value
Accepts not just strings but other types including arrays and objects, formatting them to be readable
Useful when debugging
May return its output as a return value (instead of echoing) if the second optional argument is given